# Dissipative dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

Given a time dependent dynamical system on $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the kind
$$ \dot{z}(t) = X(z(t),t), $$
if there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \mathcal{L}_Xf = \nabla_zf(z,t)\cdot X(z,t)\leq 0\;\;\forall t\in\mathbb{R}, $$
can we say the system to be dissipative?